# displaying an image from a php variable source

Tags: php, html, image

I'm trying to display an image on my website using html.

My problem is that the name of the image is saved in a php variable, so I've been trying to do the following:

```
<img src = <?php echo $fileName;?> >
```

Where &fileName is obviously the name of the file. If I simply echo this variable, it is exactly the correct file path for the operation, but the image is not displayed. Instead, on my website there's a little icon, which has nothing to do with my image. If I change it to this:

```
<img src = <?php $fileName;?> >
```

nothing at all is displayed.

I'd be grateful for any help.

Comment: Wow, that simple. Thank you all for your answers and sorry for my stupidity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the quotes:

try this:

```
<img src="<?php echo $fileName;?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<img src="<?php echo $fileName; ?>" />
```

And also check what r u getting in `echo $fileName;` as there us need full path of image to dispay.

This is because of `$fileName` may have the /(slashes) which are breaking the images tag in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the name of the image, set its path or the full URL.
And add quotes for the src property.

Answer (score 0):

Or you try Embedded code.....

```
        <?php
           echo "<img src='$filepath'/>";  
          //filepath is variable which contains path to the image file
        ?>
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Thank you for comment sir...question is about displaying the image and I hope my answer satisfies that ....